# Account creation during checkout Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i need help to change the user profile that WC sets when a user create his account during the checkout. It sets “Customer” profile.
Because i’m getting an redirection error when the users use this option (they can’t go to “online order” in the navbar) when they press click in "online order" it redirects to his account profile.
If i switch the profile “Customer” to “Suscriptor” now they can go to “online order”.
Thanks.

Comment: This question may be better suited for the [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) as it does not pertain to any coding in WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just gived the same config of "Suscriptor" to "Customer" and it works, thanks.